# Using same Variables both Module and UserForm

Tags: vba, module, userform

I tried to use the same variable at module and user, but I was not successful. I have tried to use "Public" but the user form "x" always equals 0.
Can anyone tell me where I made a mistake?

Here I want to call UserForm n times

```
' UserForm2.Show
    '  For x = 1 To n
      '  UserForm2.Show
     ' Next x
```

And here when I use UserForm every time, it should have stored the value I entered to the cells

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim x As Long
Cells(x + 1, 8).Value = cmbStok.Value
Unload UserForm2


End Sub



Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

txtResimNo.Text = CStr(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2").Value)
txtRev.Text = CStr(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C2").Value)
TxtAcık.Text = CStr(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2").Value)


cmbStok.AddItem "A: Stoktaki parçalar kullanılacaktır"
cmbStok.AddItem "B: Stoktaki parçalar tadil edildikten sonra kullanılacaktır"
cmbStok.AddItem "C: Stoktaki parçalar tadil edilemez, değişiklikten önceki cihazlar için yedek parça olarak kullanılabilir"
cmbStok.AddItem "D: Stoktaki parçalar tadil edilemez ve kullanılamaz"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define your variables as global at the top of the modul.
`global x as long`. It is not sufficient to write it as `dim x as long`. Then, remove the all other definitions for `x` in your code.

And the usual side note: Always put `option explicit` at the top of every modul.

Answer (score 0):

In your second example, you have the `Dim X As Long` in the click macro. This will narrow the scope to that range only, which is why it's always equaling zero.

I can't see exactly what you're trying to do, but consider, putting X outside of the click macro, at the top of the Userform code.

```
Dim x As Long 'put here instead, at top of code editor
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Cells(x + 1, 8).Value = cmbStok.Value
Unload UserForm2
End Sub



Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

txtResimNo.Text = CStr(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2").Value)
txtRev.Text = CStr(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C2").Value)
TxtAcık.Text = CStr(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2").Value)


cmbStok.AddItem "A: Stoktaki parçalar kullanılacaktır"
cmbStok.AddItem "B: Stoktaki parçalar tadil edildikten sonra kullanılacaktır"
cmbStok.AddItem "C: Stoktaki parçalar tadil edilemez, değişiklikten önceki cihazlar için yedek parça olarak kullanılabilir"
cmbStok.AddItem "D: Stoktaki parçalar tadil edilemez ve kullanılamaz"

End Sub
```

Comment: What i tried to do is defining variable all macro , it can be seen userform and module. For example, when "x" value is 2 in the module, i have to be 2 in the userform

Comment: I think a more accurate statement would be, "I still haven't figured out what I 'm doing incorrectly." 

I'll leave my answer up because the way you had the Dim initially setup was 100% certain to always isolate within the procedure and might help someone else searching for the same problem. I don't know what else you're doing, but something is out of order, or not part of the same procedure which is reseting, or never setting your x value.